# How to develop an Android App with google maps API on multiple computers?

Tags: android, google-maps, keytool, fingerprint

I want to make an Android Application, that uses Google Maps. I have installed Eclipse, Android JDK and an AVD (Android Virtual Device). I followed this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html and made my first app. And it works :)

But, to develop an Android app that uses Google Maps API, you have to obtain a Google Maps API Key. According to this link http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html you obtain the key by getting the MD5 fingerprint of your debug key in the JDK folder. The problem is that this fingerprint is different from computer to computer.

So my problem is this: we have to develop on multiple computers. We are using subversion as a source control on this project. How can this be solved?

If I register my MD5 fingerprint and obtain a GM API Key, this key won't work on any other computer. I know that one solution is that each and every one of the developers get their own personal API key, but I don't think this is a smooth solution.

I've tried to read up on MD5 fingerprints, and as I understand it you can create, export and import them. So, could the solution be that I create a spesific fingerprint, export it, send it to all the other developers and then they can import it? But as I understand it have to be a debug sertificate? And in that case, how to I make, export and importe one? I've treid to read up on this, and know that I use the keytool command, but I can't find any simple examples. Please enlighten me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get `debug.keystore` from one of the team members, put into Subversion and then instructy other team memebrs to replace theirs `debug.keystore` file with one from repository.

**ADD1**: See this link also: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c9051635ab37f252

**ADD2**: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode

> The default storage location for AVDs is in ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux, in C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP, and in C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: I've already tried to copy the debug.keystore file. It didn't work :(

Comment: You overwrite an old one and it didn't work? Try to restart your IDE/OS - sometimes it is getting cached somewhere.

Comment: It should work! See this link: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c9051635ab37f252 It is about the same problem.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't restart the computer last time. I'll try it again. Thanks!

Comment: I am also having almost same isuue..I am able to login to google in the app through build generated from my computer but if someone else from my team is generating build on his computer than he is not able to login AND WE ARE USING SAME KEYSTORE..I created Client ID by specifying my project package name and SHA-1 fingerprint at developer console and also created consent screen.Am i missing something on developer console?Any idea why i am facing this issue?Thanks..