# android, google map errors: BaseTileRequest, Server returned: 3

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, itemizedoverlay

I got some strange errors while develop some custom map overlays, anyone experience these? pls help, tks in advance.

```
BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)

09-17 00:53:25.933: WARN/System.err(32480): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
09-17 00:53:25.933: WARN/System.err(32480): at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
09-17 00:53:25.938: WARN/System.err(32480): at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
09-17 00:53:25.938: WARN/System.err(32480): at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
09-17 00:53:25.943: WARN/System.err(32480): at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
09-17 00:53:25.943: WARN/System.err(32480): at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
09-17 00:53:25.948: WARN/System.err(32480): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did run into this even though I followed everything said [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey).

Assuming that you did follow this link, here's how I solved the issue :

**Long story :**

Everything was working fine until I copied the whole project on another PC and imported it into Eclipse. This changes everything, because the API key you obtain is linked to the debug keystore on the machine that you used to generate the API key. Since I was running / debugging the android application on another machine (hence another debug keystore), the API key was invalid. So I had to generate a new API key as described below.

**Short story :**

If you are using another machine , **generate a new API key**, by computing the MD5 fingerprint as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getdebugfingerprint), and then generate the API key [here](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup) using this MD5 fingerprint.

Comment: But Google isn't giving API keys for version 1 anymore. In other words, if you were using v1, and happened to change the computer, you are forced to update to not-backwards-compatible v2.

Comment: But this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653882/how-to-develop-an-android-app-with-google-maps-api-on-multiple-computers

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before, it could be caused by several things, checking these things usually solves it.

1. Your map api key you use is wrong. Remember that this key is for each installation of Android, so if you have changed computer, you need to regenerate a new key. This is the most likely problem.
2. If you are using eclipse, the java build path could be bugged/set-up wrong. I've found out that the google-maps import might need to be at top or close to it in the build path declaration in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

when you are trying to get MD5 finger print, keytool command may return SH1 instead. In this case use "-v" after "keytool" command to have MD5 fingerprint as well