# Empty grid in MapView on android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to make my MapView run on android. But I get an empty grid.

I followed the exceptions and I get an error: "java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3".

I deleted my debug.keystore several times, recreated it. I created new api keys with the api console each time.

This is how I declared my MapView:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="184dp"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="0dp"
    android:apiKey="my api key"
    android:clickable="true" >
</com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

I also added several permissions in my android manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission android:name="com.example.conti_lab6.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.conti_lab6.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.conti_lab6.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.conti_lab6.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.conti_lab6.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 
</application>
```

I am out of ideas for this. I am running the emulator locally and it should use the debug.keystore in my .android file.

Comment: refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448034/android-google-map-errors-basetilerequest-server-returned-3

Comment: Are you using googlemap api v2

Comment: yes, I am using api v2. But just in case how can I check? I downloaded the lastest Google APIs and I am using the emulator for platform v17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in case of Api V2

you need some little changes

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

And you have to add the `google play library` ,And
 `The error which you are getting is generally occured when you are running your app Using v1 api key`

And for the key generating you can use SHA1 certificate with package name.

For more information check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)