# MapView in android application

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I am trying include google map in my android application.

I gone through [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) procedure to get the Map API key.

After getting the key i wrote the following code to display the map in my application.

My Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mymap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mymap.LocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Layout
     `<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="mykey"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />`

When i run the application i am getting an exception like this.

```
03-28 14:31:14.868: W/System.err(21147): IOException processing: 26

03-28 14:31:14.868: W/System.err(21147): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3

03-28 14:31:14.868: W/System.err(21147):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)

03-28 14:31:14.868: W/System.err(21147):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)

03-28 14:31:14.868: W/System.err(21147):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)

03-28 14:31:14.868: W/System.err(21147):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)

03-28 14:31:14.868: W/System.err(21147):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)

03-28 14:31:14.868: W/System.err(21147):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known error when you have a problem with your API key:

take a look at the following posts:

[android, google map errors: BaseTileRequest, Server returned: 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448034/android-google-map-errors-basetilerequest-server-returned-3)

[Google map signed api key errors in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android)

**UPDATE:**

from the link you posted for getting the Key you are getting a key for Google Map API V2 and hence it wont work with Google Maps API V1.

To integrate Google Map API V2 you can follow this blog post I wrote on this topic:

[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score 0):

Remember MapView is depreciated. Google maps V2 is supported. and you cant get a new map v1 api key.

[visit here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) to lean more about maps v2

if you are already using v2 :

Try to add following data to your manifest:

```
    <uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />  
    <permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.ikolmobile.magicmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR KEY HERE" />
```