# Error running google maps program on my samsung phone

Tags: android

I have my samsung siii connected to the eclipse through usb and use it for running my programs.
i have created a basic google maps program and trying to run on my phone through eclipse.
i have copied the sha1 code from eclipse under 
Windows -> Preferences -> android -> build

and obtained the google key from the website .
The following is my manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.chaplbs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.chaplbs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >




        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chaplbs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="mykey"/>

    </application>
```

The following is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:apiKey="my key"
   android:enabled="true"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However on running the program i get the following error :

```
06-20 15:23:51.262: W/System.err(28660): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I am trying to figure out the problem.
Does my running the program on my mobile rather than emulator generating this error.
kindly update
thanks
tejinder

Comment: map api v1 is deprecated. use map ap1 v2

Comment: Are you referring to use of MapView .but even if deprecated it should run .

Comment: switch to map api v2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: Almost certainty a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448034/android-google-map-errors-basetilerequest-server-returned-3

Comment: Can we not use MapView with our Google Maps key v2 as i am able to view Map with Fragment but not with MapView.can you update on this