# Android google map don't show

Tags: android, google-maps

I use google map in project, but it is dont work rightly. I have registred Google map Api Key in google services and add in my project AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value=" Api key" />
```

But it is don't show map you can see it in this picture:
[image]

When i run my app,  in tab Anroid Monitor of Android Studio i have this error:

[image]

I can't find resolve.

and in Api monitor i have this error too, when i open app

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
```

Comment: Have you enabled the API from the Google developer's console as well?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes i have enabled well

Comment: Have you added the generate api key in your code

Comment: Yes i have added: 
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value=" Api key" />

Comment: I suggest doing some searching. For example - the claim is that you're using the wrong methods or the API key is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448034/android-google-map-errors-basetilerequest-server-returned-3... If you are sure it is correct, then add a [mcve] of the code to your question

Answer (score 0):

Did you added ***play-services*** dependency in gradle file?

Comment: Yes i add play-services in dependency

Comment: @cricket_007 i add dependency in gradle

Comment: did you added `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`
 field in your fragment?

Comment: You should ask for the question to be edited  with code instead of guessing about what's been done

Answer (score 0):

If Possible change your play-service dependency and set dependency based on  building tools installed or api installed, like following way

**From**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
```

**To**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
```

Comment: it is my defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packageName"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    } 
I can't use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'

Comment: First change your target version which very low, Then put your dependancy part

Comment: I have do it, but i have error: 
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources
AND this
java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3

Comment: Yes you can use.

Comment: Why are you guessing which version was used? @aimp Please explain why you think those errors prevent you from using a different version of the library? The latest being 11.2.0, so I don't know why anything older than that is suggested for a new app

Comment: @cricket_007 I am suggesting just because Issue related google com.google.map.jar not found in exception so possibility to issue by play-service or sdk.